# OpenGL, GLUT, GLEW - window always blank white

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut, glew

I am using **Dell XPS 9550, x64 Windows 10**. with graphics card **GeForce GTX 960M**. using **Visual Studio 2017 C++**

OpenGL using GLUT and GLEW does not work while things work fine with GLFW.

I've been using OpenGL for a while, so I am pretty sure I linked header files, libs and dll correctly.

Also, I tested exactly the same project in other computer, and worked fine without any problem.

So I was wondering maybe there exist some compatibility issues with the graphic card? Anyone have any idea?

It should render like this (**Desktop Windows 10 x64, GTX 1050**):
[image]

But on **Dell XPS 9550 (GeForce GTX 960M)**, blank window shows up:
[image]

The code I used is:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 320
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 240

void display();
void init();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow("Main Window");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // next four lines are new
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, WINDOW_WIDTH - 1, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 1, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);
    glVertex2f(10, 10);
    glVertex2f(100, 10);
    glVertex2f(100, 100);
    glVertex2f(10, 100);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: have you found a way out? I have the exact same problem, except its on windows 7, 64-bits.Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: it was the DELL graphics card problem. not the OpenGL stuff.

Comment: I restored Window to its factory presets, and it worked. Just don't do any of those BIOS and NVDIA updates  afterward